# How to encode English plain-text (consisting only of letters a-z and whitespace) using a 5-bit character encoding in Python?

Tags: python, character-encoding

in Python, is there any way to encode English plain-text (consisting only of small letters a-z and whitespace - i.e. a total of 27 characters) using 5-bit character-encoding? If yes, please do tell me how.

To be more specific, say I have a string: 
s="hello world". After encoding this using 5-bit character-encoding in Python I want to save this string to an external file such that each of the character in that file will only take 5-bits of storage space.

Comment: How long is the text? And do you insist on 5-bit encoding, or do you just want to compress it *some* way?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sorry, I would like strictly insist on 5-bit encoding, not compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to convert characters from ASCII to 5-bit encoding. It's up to you how to do it. One possible straight-forward way:

```
class TooMuchBits(Exception):
    pass

def encode_str(data):
    buf = bytearray()
    for char in data:
        num = ord(char)

        # Lower case latin letters
        if num >= 97 and num <= 122:
            buf.append(num - 96)

        # Space
        elif num == 32:
            buf.append(27)

        else:
            raise TooMuchBits(char)

    return buf

def decode_str(data):
    buf = bytearray()
    for num in data:
        if num == 27:
            buf.append(' ')
        else:
            buf.append(chr(num+96))

    return bytes(buf)
```

After it you have 5-bit numbers which can be packed into 8-bit bytes. Something like this:

```
# This should not be more than 8
BITS = 5

def get_last_bits(value, count):
    return value & ((1<<count) - 1)

def pack(data):
    buf = bytearray(1)
    used_bits = 0

    for num in data:
        # All zeroes is a special value marking unused bits
        if not isinstance(num, int) or num <= 0 or num.bit_length() > BITS:
            raise TooMuchBits(num)

        # Character fully fits into available bits in current byte
        if used_bits <= 8 - BITS:
            buf[-1] |= num << used_bits
            used_bits += BITS

        # Character should be split into two different bytes
        else:
            # Put lowest bit into available space
            buf[-1] |= get_last_bits(num, 8 - used_bits) << used_bits
            # Put highest bits into next byte
            buf.append(num >> (8 - used_bits))
            used_bits += BITS - 8

    return bytes(buf)

def unpack(data):
    buf = bytearray()
    data = bytearray(data)

    # Characters are filled with logic AND and therefore initialized with zero
    char_value = 0
    char_bits_left = BITS

    for byte in data:
        data_bits_left = 8

        while data_bits_left >= char_bits_left:
            # Current character ends in current byte
            # Take bits from current data bytes and shift them to appropriate position
            char_value |= get_last_bits(byte, char_bits_left) << (BITS - char_bits_left)

            # Discard processed bits
            byte = byte >> char_bits_left
            data_bits_left -= char_bits_left

            # Zero means the end of the string. It's necessary to detect unused space in the end of data
            # It's otherwise possible to detect such space as a 0x0 character
            if char_value == 0:
                break

            # Store and initialize character 
            buf.append(char_value)
            char_value = 0
            char_bits_left = BITS

        # Collect bits left in current byte
        if data_bits_left:
            char_value |= byte
            char_bits_left -= data_bits_left

    return buf
```

This seems to work as expected:

```
test_string = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

encoded = encode_str(test_string)
packed = pack(encoded)
unpacked = unpack(packed)
decoded = decode_str(unpacked)

print "Test str (len: %d): %r" % (len(test_string), test_string)
print "Encoded (len: %d):  %r" % (len(encoded), encoded)
print "Packed (len: %d):   %r" % (len(packed), packed)
print "Unpacked (len: %d): %r" % (len(unpacked),unpacked)
print "Decoded (len: %d):  %r" % (len(decoded), decoded)
```

Outputs:

```
Test str (len: 43): 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
Encoded (len: 43):  bytearray(b'\x14\x08\x05\x1b\x11\x15\t\x03\x0b\x1b\x02\x12\x0f\x17\x0e\x1b\x06\x0f\x18\x1b\n\x15\r\x10\x13\x1b\x0f\x16\x05\x12\x1b\x14\x08\x05\x1b\x0c\x01\x1a\x19\x1b\x04\x0f\x07')
Packed (len: 27):   '\x14\x95\x1dk\x1ak\x0b\xf9\xae\xdb\xe6\xe1\xadj\x83s?[\xe4\xa6\xa8l\x16t\xde\xe4\x1d'
Unpacked (len: 43): bytearray(b'\x14\x08\x05\x1b\x11\x15\t\x03\x0b\x1b\x02\x12\x0f\x17\x0e\x1b\x06\x0f\x18\x1b\n\x15\r\x10\x13\x1b\x0f\x16\x05\x12\x1b\x14\x08\x05\x1b\x0c\x01\x1a\x19\x1b\x04\x0f\x07')
Decoded (len: 43):  'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

Comment: Here it's not possible to use all 32 values for 5-bits because of end-of-line detection. This is necessary to distinguish between last 0x0 char and unused space in last byte. It is also possible to avoid it by storing string length somewhere else.

Comment: Really awesome. Thanks a lot. TBH I haven't really understood the code properly, but when I saved the encoded test_string to an external file I can see that the file size is just 29 bytes (I hope the extra 2 bytes are for EOL detection) whereas in 8-bit encoding it is 43 bytes. That means it worked like a charm. :-)

Please let me ask one doubt, after saving the result to an external file "foo" i tried running: `print decode_str(unpack(open("ooo.txt", "r").read()))` which printed just 'the qu`. For a different test_string decoding worked well, why is this?

Comment: Most likely this happens because of 5th byte. With this string it is 0x1A which is a special [substitute character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) often used in Microsoft systems to indicate EOF. I do not have enough experience with Python on Windows but guess that binary mode will help you. Just use `open("file", "wb")` to write and `open("file", "rb")` to read. By the way, this may help cutting 2 extra bytes. On my system I get 27 bytes in the file.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best recognised 5-bit encoding is [Baudot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code) (and its derivatives ITA2 and USTTY). Properly speaking this is a shift-based encoding with separate letter and figure shifts, but you can confine your output to the letter shift.

Here's a quick example of encoding (encoding table taken from http://code.google.com/p/tweletype/source/browse/baudot.py):

```
import string
letters = "\x00E\x0AA SIU\x0DDRJNFCKTZLWHYPQOBG\x0EMXV\x0F"
s = "Hello World"
for c in string.upper(s):
    print letters.find(c)
```

Comment: First of all thanks. In the given example (if I am correct) if I save the output of this to an external file then each of the character in that file will use up 8 bits, right? What I actually need is to encode each character using only 5 bits. Really sorry for not being specific about that in the question. I will edit my question to make it more clear. Thanks again (Sorry that I can't vote up this answer due to insufficient reputation).

Answer (score 1):

How about *less* than five bits? Testing with the first paragraph of the [translated Lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum#English_translation):

```
import gzip
text = 'But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?'
text = ''.join(c for c in text.lower() if c.islower() or c == ' ')
encoded = gzip.compress(text.encode())
decoded = gzip.decompress(encoded).decode()
print('%.3f' % (len(encoded) / len(text) * 8), 'bits per char')
print('Roundtrip ok?', decoded == text)
print(len(set(text)), 'different chars in text')
```

The result:

```
4.135 bits per char
Roundtrip ok? True
26 different chars in text
```

Compression like this takes advantage not only of the fact that there are only 27 chars but also of the different probabilities as well as patterns.

I also tried lzma and bz2 instead of gzip, but for this particular example, gzip compressed best.

Comment: Thanks. But instead of a compression program like this what I am actually looking for is that if I save the output to an external file then each of the character in it should only take 5 bits. Sorry for not being specific in the question, I will edit it now.

Comment: @AmbadyanandS But why is 5 bits better than 4.135 bits?

Comment: So that I think it can be compressed again by using some compression programs later (such as the compression methods you mentioned earlier).

Comment: @AmbadyanandS Huh? That will either make no difference or be *worse* than compressing directly. Likely the latter.

Comment: Can you please tell me how? Have you really checked it by yourself?

Comment: @AmbadyanandS How what? How it can be worse? Because for example "e" is one of the most common letters in the original text, and the compressor will recognize that and can take advantage of it. If you, however, merge it with another letter or two into the same byte, then the compressor won't have that advantage. There'll still be patterns, but since 5 and 8 are coprime, it's gonna be pretty scattered.

Comment: @AmbadyanandS I didn't check 5-bit encoding followed by other compression (because I don't have a 5-bit encoder), but I did check regular compression of *random* letters (and spaces) and it still was under 5 bits on average (for decently large inputs). Like I said in my answer, regular compression does take advantage of the fact that there are only 27 chars. It's not just about patterns (of which there aren't any in random data).

Comment: Really thanks. Anyway I would still like to know if there is anyway for 5-bit encoding, just for the sake of curiosity. So I am letting this question remain opened. Thanks again, I really mean it.